# In a directed graph with $n \geq 2$ nodes, if two different nodes reaches $n$ nodes, then this graph has a directed cycle.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, computer-science

I think this statement is true because if first node can reaches every other node (including second node) and second node can reaches every other nodes (including first node), then first node and second node would form a cycle. But I am just wondering how can I construct a proper proof.

Comment: What is meant by two different nodes reach $n$ nodes? You mean two nodes both being able to reach every node (including itself)?

Comment: yes, sorry for the poor wording

Comment: It sounds like you already have a proof: If node $a$ and node $b$ both reach everything, then by definition there is a path from $a$ to $b$ and a path from $b$ to $a$. Concatenating these two paths will produce a path from $a$ to $a$ of nonzero length (because it also contains $b$) -- that is, a cycle. If you require a "cycle" to be simple (that is, have no repeated nodes), then prove separately that a graph with a non-simple cycle has a simple cycle too. [This is easily done by long induction on the length of the non-simple cycle].

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the long induction on the length of the non-simple cycle? I am not too sure what that means.